# Setup MantisBT to accept RFP

Tags: bug-report

How can I change mantisbt so it can have a RFP type issue. Basically I want to publish a link to my website. And potential clients can go to my mantis and report an RFP issue. RFP issue should have different fields than a Bug issue. Also a Bug issue is project specific but RFP is not like that. And all RFP issues should be private to reporter. I have some public projects too. I dont want someone else get project Idea by reading an RFP.

How could I do it in mantis? If there is any other open source PHP based bug tracker that supports such mechanism please mention. My preference is to use mantis as I am using this for many other projects already.

Comment: No answer?? Seems no one uses mantis-bt

Comment: RFP = request for proposal ? Why are you do fixated on using mantis when rfps are nothing like defects ? Why not find some other package that is more suited to purpose ?

Comment: I have used mantis and it is very customizable so if you really wanted to go down this route you could, but why ?

Comment: @Phil RFP=Request for proposal, yes. I saw JIRA has such functionality. So I thought May be MantisBT could be modified to do that. Besides I am quite familiar with Mantis. Do you know any other lightweight software that can handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to use a bug tracking system for tracking issues in a Request for Proposal? You could just do that via comments / editing features in the word program you use.

You could use Google Docs to create a spreadsheet and put a link to that public document on your website for reporting RFP issues. Better yet you could create an RFP issues document for the specific doc and include the link in the RFP for issue tracking.  Wouldn't you want RFPs to be non public?

With Google Docs you could control who had access to them but you wouldn't need to create / manage different users. You could create a read only template and every time you need to create one, just make a copy and begin editing it.

This isn't really a testing question but I hope this brainstorming will help.

Comment: The reason for using a BT for RFP is nothing, I saw one of the company doing it using JIRA. And yes RFPs should be non-public. But Entry form should be public

Comment: Do you know how or why that specific company used JIRA? You might want to figure out if it was a good idea or not before trying it yourself.